# apoc.load.jsonParams as POST request with Body input parameters

Tags: c#, rest, post, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

In the documentation of Neo4j for **apoc.load.jsonParams** there is an example how to make a POST request:

```
CALL apoc.load.jsonParams(
  "https://neo4j.com/docs/search/",
  {method: "POST"},
  apoc.convert.toJson({query: "subquery", version: "4.0"})
);
```

but unfortunately this is not sufficient for me because I also need a body with parameters for the POST request:

```
[HttpPost("getJson")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetJson(int id, [FromBody] List<string> params)
```

My try:

```
CALL apoc.load.jsonParams("http://192.168.1.128:4040/api/getJson?id=17",{method: "POST"}, "$.BusinessData[*]") YIELD value WITH ["DATA1", "DATA2"] as body return *
```

Error message:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.jsonParams`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't read url or key http://192.168.1.128:4040/api/getJson?id=17 as json: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL
```

So how must the apoc call look like to fullfill the POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the apoc.load.jsonParams documentation:

> apoc.load.jsonParams(urlOrKey :: STRING?, headers :: MAP?, payload ::
> STRING?, path =  :: STRING?, config = {} :: MAP?) :: (value :: MAP?)

Transport the body as payload parameter and convert it with `apoc.convert.toJson` to Json string list. Also it's needed to define the `Content-Type` as `application/json` in the header. (do not overlook the backticks)

```
CALL apoc.load.jsonParams("http://192.168.1.128:4040/api/getJson?id=17", 
{`Content-Type`:"application/json"}, apoc.convert.toJson(["DATA1", "DATA2"]), "$.BusinessData[*]") YIELD value as item
```